# How to restrict global snippets to show only for certain file extensions in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I manage my [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) in a single `MyGlobal.code-snippets` file.

I'd like to restrict individual snippets to show only for certain languages. For example, below snippet should occur only in jsx,tsx files.

```json
"useEffect(() => {\"\"},[]);": {
    "prefix": "useEffect",
    "body": ["useEffect(() => {", "$0", "},[]);"],
    "description": "useEffect(()=>{},[])"
  },
```

According to VSCode docs, we can do that by adding [language scope](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-scope), However, it's not working in my case. If I add scope, it stops occurring in any files including jsx,tsx.

```json
"useEffect(() => {\"\"},[]);": {
    "prefix": "useEffect",
    "scope": "jsx,tsx",
    "body": ["useEffect(() => {", "$0", "},[]);"],
    "description": "useEffect(()=>{},[])"
  },
```

I know there's a way to have language-specific snippet files but I prefer to manage all user snippets inside a single file.

Comment: are you sure that are the languageIDs for the files, don't use extensions

Comment: @rioV8 what are lunaguageIDs now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [languageIDs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers)

```
"useEffect(() => {\"\"},[]);": {
    "prefix": "useEffect",
    "scope": "javascriptreact,typescriptreact",
    "body": ["useEffect(() => {", "$0", "},[]);"],
    "description": "useEffect(()=>{},[])"
  },
```

Comment: How would you restrict a snippet to a header file (.h) in the C language?

Comment: @NicolasMiari the header file does not have a different languageID compared to the C/C++ file, so it is not possible to restrict it to `.h` files only

Comment: when i write json prop `"scope"` it says that scope property not allowed is it deprecated?

Comment: @sairfan https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_project-snippet-scope